# Lock entire table stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Guys I have a stored procedure that inserts a new value in the table, only when the last inserted value is different.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PutData]
    @date datetime,
    @value float
AS
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Sensor1 WHERE SensorTime <= @date AND SensorTime = (SELECT MAX(SensorTime) FROM Sensor1) AND SensorValue = @value)
        INSERT INTO Sensor1 (SensorTime, SensorValue) VALUES (@date, @value)
RETURN 0
```

Now, since I'm doing this at a high frequency (say every 10ms), the `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT)` statement is often getting old data, and because of this I'm getting duplicate data. Would it be possible to lock the entire table during the stored procedure, to make sure the `SELECT` statement always receives the latest data?

Comment: Can you describe what you are actually trying to do?  I think the problem is with your design.  Locking the table is going to be problematic, because then other calls to the SP are going to be waiting for the table to unlock.

Comment: Hi, this SO question has some relevance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21086201/fill-in-missing-values I have a table with 2 columns, datetime (with PK) and a float (which holds the value). The system is monitoring a machine, and every ~10ms receives data with a datetime and it should be inserted in the table. To save storage the plan is to only insert the value when it differs from the last inserted value. So the table results should look like the SO question I linked above.

Comment: You should add them to a different queue table unconditionally (ie. always) and then use a procedure to move them into the real table at intervals, this would then probably not have to run every 10ms.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but cannot you move that inserts to a (no indexed) stag table and in a late point in time do all necessary (batch) inserts at Sensor table?

Comment: The problem with that is that I want to display the data in real time. But it's definitely a possibility I should consider

Answer (score 0):

According to the poster's comments to the question, c# code receives a value from a sensor.  The code is supposed to insert the value only if it is different from the previous value.

Rather than solving this in the database, why not have the code store the last value inserted and only invoke the procedure if the new value is different?  Then the procedure will not need to check whether the value exists in the database; it can simply insert.  This will be much more efficient.

Comment: Wouldn't that be much slower? I'm calling this SP from a C# application, and then I would have to call 2 SP's, one for the select and one for the insert.

Comment: How can that be beneficial for his problem ? If the time between the IF () and INSERT already is too large to avoid stale data then how can going to the database to find out if the information from the IF(), coming back to the machine, deciding and (potentially) doing the INSERT be any faster ????? Solving this inside the database is exactly what's needed here.

Comment: @user3182508, am I misunderstanding the issue?  Please clarify if what I suggested won't work.

Comment: On top of that, there is no such a thing as a 'global variable' in MSSQL. Anyway, assuming all the data comes from a single program then it might indeed be possible to filter out the INSERT when the data isn't changed. Somehow I think the caller already thought about that but had reasons to have to do things differently. (PS: maybe I need to refresh, but there is nowhere I can see he has a c# program that receives values from a sensor)

Comment: I have a C# program that receives data from a sensor, and he sends that data through HTTP to different web-api applications that call the SP. @dan1111 I have tried creating a static value in my c# code, but it seems that there is also delay when i up the frequency to 10ms, and gives me duplicate values

Comment: @user3182508, my preference would be to solve that problem and do it on the c# side, because in my opinion, executing this kind of query on the database every 10ms will be very problematic.

Comment: @deroby, my mistake, I am used to using other RDBMs, and didn't realize SQL Server lacks global variables.

Comment: Removed the down-vote as the suggestion to do the filtering at the base does indeed make sense now we get more information about the situation (Going up and down to the database every 10ms over http is going to be troublesome indeed), then again, it's not an answer to the actual question .. (although it might be to the problem).
The main question is if the data will have a single source or may come from different (independent) ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PutData]
    @date datetime,
    @value float
AS

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        INSERT INTO Sensor1 (SensorTime, SensorValue) 
        SELECT SensorTime = @date, 
               SensorValue = @value
         WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                            FROM Sensor1 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
                           WHERE SensorValue = @value
                             AND SensorTime <= @date 
                             AND SensorTime = (SELECT MAX(SensorTime) FROM Sensor1) )

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

RETURN 0
```

Thinking a bit about it, you could probably write it like this too:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[PutData]
    @date datetime,
    @value float
AS

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

        INSERT INTO Sensor1 (SensorTime, SensorValue) 
        SELECT SensorTime = @date, 
               SensorValue = @value
          FROM (SELECT TOP 1 SensorValue, SensorTime
                  FROM Sensor1 WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
                 ORDER BY SensorTime DESC) last_value
         WHERE last_value.SensorTime <= @date 
           AND last_value.SensorValue <> @value

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

RETURN 0
```

Assuming you have a unique index (PK?) on SensorTime this should be quite fast actually.

Comment: There is indeed a PK on SensorTime. The second one does seem to improve things quite a bit, I'm going to test it some more